removed snapd and cannot install it anymore (ubuntu 24.04LTS)
One of my snaps didn't start anymore on Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop. Removing that snap and reinstalling it didn't work. After some quick research I made the stupid decision to remove snapd with apt-get (sudo apt-get remove snapd).
I try for 3 days to install it again without any result.
I removed all data related to snap (made a backup of my ~/snap dir).
This is the error message I'm getting:
$ sudo apt-get install snap snapd -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  snap snapd
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 113 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.63+24.04 [28.1 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 snap amd64 2013-11-29-11 [377 kB]
Fetched 28.4 MB in 15s (1,896 kB/s)                                            
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsnapd-glib-2-1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 355786 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.63+24.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.63+24.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.63+24.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 error setting timestamps of '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-update-ns.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package snap.
Preparing to unpack .../snap_2013-11-29-11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snap (2013-11-29-11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.63+24.04_amd64.deb
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.6 ]
File updated: searched for 181 files, found 144
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I cleared the following directories:
~/snap
/var/lib/snap
/var/snap
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libsnapd-glib-2-1:amd64*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.63+24.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt remove --purge snapd
sudo apt purge snapd snap-confine
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref <- not there

Then rebooted the system and started all fresh with:
sudo apt-get install snapd

I keep getting this same error about the timestamp of snap-update-ns.dpkg-new, but that file is not there.
Could some please help me? I can't find a solution online.

Feels like this is an issue with the snapd-update. As we both have the issues since this weekend, I figured I could try to find an older version.
As installing the current snapd fails, I looked at the available ones in my distro:
apt list --all-versions snapd

And then picked the older of the two:
sudo apt install snapd=2.62+24.04build1

That installation worked. Next I rebooted and tried the snap list. Nope.
snap install firefox
error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/firefox": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

It makes sense as I removed pretty much everything to get the issue resolved. The issue I now had was that the deamon wasn't starting anymore.
~ systemctl status snapd
○ snapd.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit snapd.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ snapd.socket
➜  ~ systemctl start snapd
Failed to start snapd.service: Unit snapd.service is masked.

And that could be resolved with:
~ sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service
Removed "/etc/systemd/system/snapd.service".
➜  ~ sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service.
➜  ~ sudo systemctl start snapd.service
➜  ~ snap install firefox
2024-07-15T17:05:56+02:00 INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
firefox 128.0-2 from Mozilla✓ installed



Thanks a lot Localhost, that did the trick for me too. The service started correct on my system. Marked yours as solution

I think this could be an actual bug in snapd_2.63+24.04_amd64.deb. I've created a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/2073215. The error returns the next time my machine tries to update. Luckily the snap apps keep working.
